# How do you implement basic nginx rate limiting?

Tags: nginx, nginx-config, rate-limiting

I am trying to test a basic nginx rate limiting setup for an API built with Nodejs and deployed on a DigitalOcean droplet.

I am expecting a 503 error to be returned when a client makes more than 1 request per minute(a low limit for testing). At the moment, a client can continue to make as many requests as they like.

In `nginx.conf`, I have tried including the following in the `http` block -

```
    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/s;

    server {

        location / {
            limit_req zone=one burst=5;
        }
```

I have also tried including the above in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` file by adding a separate `http` and `server` blocks.

I have referred to these resources - [resource 1](https://www.nginx.com/blog/rate-limiting-nginx/), [resource 2](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_limit_req_module.html).

Any and all help is greatly appreciated. Please let me know if I can provide further information to help with clarifying my problem.

**UPDATE**

The following configuration update to `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` seems to have fixed the problem.

In the main context I included:

```
# Rate Limiting
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=by_ip:10m rate=7r/s;
```

In the location context nested inside the server context I included:

```
server {

        root /var/www/html;

        server_name <SERVER NAMES>;

        location / {
                limit_req zone=by_ip;
                proxy_pass http://localhost:<PORT VALUE>;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your nginx-configuration snippet that you give will make a rate-limit of 1 request per **second** (`rate=1r/s`)

With the `burst=5`-setting you will also open a "queue" with 5 entries. This means that a client can make 5 requests in a row and further requests will get a "delay" of 1 second but will still get through.

For you goal to set a "hard" limit of 1 request per minute you would need this configuration:

```
limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=one:10m rate=1r/m;

server {

    location / {
        limit_req zone=one nodelay;
    }
}
```

Important is the `rate=1r/m` which will set the rate limit to 1 request per **minute**. (This is the lowest settings that nginx supports.)

Then the `nodelay` means, that you will cancel any further requests in this minute with a `503` (the default status code for a rate limit).

Comment: Thankyou @DanEEStar for the clear response. I have implemented the above configuration but the problem persists. In my original post I didn't explicitly mention I was using nginx as a proxy for the nodeJS server. In case that wasn't apparent, would this change how I should be configuring rate limiting? I read [this](https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/security-controls/controlling-access-proxied-http/) article which suggests it wouldn't. My thanks again.

Comment: It should not make a difference if it is a proxy... A different `location`-config could maybe interfere. It could help if you could add more of your existing configuration.

Comment: thanks for the note. I updated the initial post to include the change to configuration which seems to work. The problem I have now is when tested with Postman, when the request limit is exceeded I get a 503 error as expected, however, when requests are made from a live site, the console error is a CORS error and, curiously, in the network tab the general headers has a status code of 503. Why would the console log a CORS error? Perhaps this should be separate post.